# terminal mac - bash command not found, permission denied and '&gt' in prompt

Tags: bash, macos, terminal, permission-denied

I tried to change colors in terminal following this guide:
http://osxdaily.com/2013/02/05/improve-terminal-appearance-mac-os-x/

I created bash_profile file, saved and quit terminal. Now when I open the terminal I get this:

```
Last login: Mon Oct 17 01:36:24 on ttys000

-bash:  : command not found

-bash:  : command not found

-bash:    git: command not found

-bash: gt: command not found

-bash: /dev/null: Permission denied
```

->> $   this last line is changed on stackoverflow. I do not understand why. Please look at the photo below.

I deleted bash_profile and I still get the same.

[image]

Comment: This Q is not about programming as defined for StackOverflow. It **may** be more appropriate on the SE sites http://apple.stackexchange.com  (AskDifferent) OR http://SuperUser.com .Use the `flag` link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it there. Please don't post the same Q on 2 different sites. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/tour , http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask , and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve 
Good Luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did not use the flag asking for moving the post as suggested in the comment because I had already posted the same post on AskDifferent.

The answer to the problem is on AskDifferent:
https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/257603/terminal-change-of-colours-guide-file-bash-profile-bash-not-found-permissi

The problem with a syntax error is caused by HTML markup in the source I copy/pasted this from.